# Simple for loop with JsRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I'm using JsRender to render a template client-side. However, I'm unable to use the for loop tag to repeat an html-portion of the block because it seems to accept only arrays or objects. Instead, my JSON return a variable which is a number (the number of times I should repeat the block). How can I repeat html N times using JsRender?

Comment: Instead of putting -1 and going away, please comment so that if my question is not clear I can edit it

Comment: Have you tried the whole html block in an array?

Comment: what do you mean by "whole block in an array"? The block is a simple html portion that I should repeat N times. With PHP it's a simple range-based for loop, however I don't find a way to do it with JsRender

Comment: if you have a block with the code `<div>Something that I want to write</div>`. Then, you can put this whole long "string" in an array. One block of html code is equivalent to 1 array. Then, repeat the array.

Comment: this won't work because I don't get from the response an HTML block but only a number saying how many times it must be repeated

Comment: I think the best thing to do here is not to use jsrender for this kind of problem, since you can not put the number of repetitions. Instead, use javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, that JsRender provide this functionality from the box. You can write your own tag, like here: [Example Scenario: Creating custom helpers to iterate through fields](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/scenarios/03_iterating-through-fields-scenario.html)

```
$.views.helpers({
    getFields: function( count ) {
        var fieldsArray = [];
        for (var i=0; i < count; i++) {
            fieldsArray.push({});
        }

        return fieldsArray;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6UeZC/

Answer (score 4):

I extended @webdeveloper answer, as there is no need for additional loop because javascript arrays are working in a way that you only have to define last element

```
$.views.helpers({
    repeatLoop: function( count ) {
        if (!count) return [];
        var repeat = [];
        repeat[count-1] = {};
        return repeat;
    }
});
```

And then use as

```
@{{for ~repeatLoop(10)}}
    {{:#index+1}}
@{{/for}}
```